# Configure the return_type field in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth

I'm using the `AuthenticationBuilder.AddOAuth(...)` method to add OAuth functionality to my site. This is working perfectly for one service I am connecting to, but the same doesn't go for the second service.

Apparently, during the redirect to the authorization endpoint, the second service requires the URL parameter `return_type` to be set to `token`, my configuration sets it to `code` though. I haven't been able to find what part of the `OAuthOptions` determines this parameter so far.

---

I'll add the code I am using for convenience:

```cs
authBuilder.AddOAuth(Identifier, options =>
{
    options.ClientId = ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString($"/signin-{Identifier}");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/");
    
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Domain + AuthorizationEndpoint;
    options.TokenEndpoint = Domain + TokenEndpoint;
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = Domain + UserInfoEndpoint;

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, NameIdentifierKey);
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, NameKey);

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

            var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

            context.RunClaimActions(user.RootElement);
        }
    };

    options.Scope.Add(Scope);
});
```

Comment: return_type is part of which OAuth flow you use. `Code` is Authorization Code Flow, `token` is part of Implicit Flow. Not quite sure what you mean by "service". Your service should not require a certain flow to be used, it should require an access token, which is the **result** of the redirect, not **how** you get it. Unlesss by "service" you mean that you are using completely different authorization endpoints, and one of them does not support the code flow.

Comment: It seems like that's the issue. By "service" I am referring to the website which offers an OAuth endpoint. So the ASP.NET Core OAuth Middleware does not support more control over the query parameters?

Comment: Apparently the `response_type` query parameter is hardcoded into the source ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/7e14b052ea9cb935ec4f5cb0485b4edb5d41297a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthHandler.cs#L230)).